# Tomcat behaving differently on different machines

Tags: tomcat, web, vaadin

I'm using the Vaadin framework, my web.xml looks as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin application class to start</description>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        Application widgetset</description>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>MyWidgetset</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservletname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Furthermore, my application directory looks as follows:

```
    .
    ├── (various xml config files)
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── ...
    ├── static
    │   ├── styles.css
    │   ├── welcome_de.html
    │   └── welcome_fr.html
    ├── trustStore.jks
    ├── VAADIN
    │   └──   ...
    └── WEB-INF
        ├── lib
        │   └── (various libraries)
        └── web.xml
```

My objective is to access `welcome_de.html` and `welcome_fr.html` statically.
So far so good. On my test-machine where I run a Tomcat instance right from eclipse (tomcat version 6.0.32), everything works fine. I can access the file using the URL:

`http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/static/`

If I export and deploy the WAR-file to the productive Tomcat server, it behaves differently.

Accessing the same file on my productive server (tomcat version 6.0.18), I get an error 404. For debugging purposes, I enabled the `listing` property for the `default` servlet. And I found that I can only access `welcome_de.html` using

`http://productive:8080/MyApplication/static/static/welcome_de.html`. If I use the same link as on the test here, I'll get the content of my webapplication.

Somehow, the folder `static` seems to be nested in itself for one level.

Any idea ? Why does it behave differently for two machines - whereas there's no major version difference?

Unfortunately, upgrading the productive server to version 6.0.32 isn't an option.

Comment: is there some reverse proxy installed? it seems like something else is different besides a minor difference in tomcat versions

Comment: not that I know of. Any idea to verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - I solved it differently. I just let Vaadin serve the file and then read it using a Filepath. It seems to work, although there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is really **just a guess**, so please don't blame me for it.

As I was trying to load different kind of files using eclipse and Tomcat I experienced something similar. On the local eclipse Tomcat it ran perfectly fine, while on the real application server did not.

The reason in the end, at least for me, was how I loaded the files internally.

I found out that my problems didn't occure anymore when I use the getResourceAsStream("path from project in working space") method, e.g. (a code snippet from my application where I also use OpenNLP)

```
    try (InputStream modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/documentProcessor/algorithms/pos-maxent.bin")) {
        ...
    }
```

"documentProcessor", "algorithms" etc is simply the filepath to the external file from the project in my workspace that I wanted to be included in my web application.

I don't know how you include your *.html files into your vaadin application, but if you load them somehow it might be worth the try.

Comment: Your idea is good, but I think you're looking in the wrong direction. Even though I solved the problem differently, I took a look at your solution. It's not about reading the file correctly... this would work. It's about that the file isn't located where it should be. With the static mapping, I'm not handling the file serving myself, I let tomcat do it. Therefore, this doesn't change anything. Thanks for the good tip anyway.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, just a guess :) Good luck!

Comment: No problem, I'm not blaming you at all! Thanks for having tried.